# how to get value from parent url to iframe

Tags: php, facebook

Suppose the URL is `http://apps.facebook.com/hellp?id=12367` .
my website is **iframed** in `http://apps.facebook.com/hellp?id=12367`.
 I need to retrieve the value 1237 To my Iframed url. 
I tried php get but it does'nt work.
I am wondering if there is any solution.

Answer (score 2):

All parameters you add to application canvas URL just passed to application, but you should retrieve the parameters from `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` but not `$_GET`, since Facebook loading your application in `iframe` tag by issuing `POST` request.

```
print_r($_POST['id']);
```

Comment: are you sure? I can't see parameters added in the facebook url inside my $_REQUEST array.

Comment: @Pons, yep, I'm sure. For application canvas (not Page Tab canvas) arguments in URL passed to your application untouched. If you can't access 'em than probably you have some code that strips that data. You can try to check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and/or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to see 'em passed...

Comment: @Pons, also have in mind that `$_REQUEST` content may vary according to PHP settings. See [`variables-order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) and [`request_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order)